# OCS 2007 R2 Group Chat Client takes a long time to start

Tags: ms-office-communicator, instant-messaging

We are using OCS 2007 R2 with Group Chat. The Group Chat client starts up quickly on our Windows 7 boxes, but takes over two minutes (!) to start on our Windows XP SP3 boxes. The July 2010 hotfix has been applied to all of the clients.

This has become a huge issue because users get no indication at all that the program is loading until it is finished. We have to do training over and over again to tell users to wait at least two minutes for the application to start, even though they see nothing on the screen. Our Windows network is isolated from the Internet as has no external connectivity. I suspect that the client is waiting on a timeout of some sort.  Has anyone else experienced this issue?

I know that this application is a dog, but it is what we have for now, and I could really, really use some help from the community.